# Defining a function in order to easily define what Excel file to read

Tags: python

So I want to define a function in order to read a file, lets say I have the following hypothetical address (please note that I am fairly new to coding and especially functions, I understand reading them but can not work with them yet):

```
C:\Users\example\data01
```

If I would make it easy for myself, I would do it as follows:

```
df= pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\example\data01")
```

But now I want to create a function so that you only have to fill in data01, I tried the following but it did not work (I already found out that I had to use double slashes):

```
def address(name):
    base = "C:\\Users\\example\\"
    end = ".csv"
    address= f"r'"{base}{name}{end}"
    return address

full_address = address('data01')
```

But the ' complicates this and I do not know how to solve this! Any tips please?

In the end I want to do this so I am able to read multiple files without adding much code.

Comment: Why are you constructing `address` like this? What's `r'"` supposed to do? Why not just `address = f'{base}{name}{end}'`?

Comment: In order to show that backslashes are interpreted as actual backslashes, r stands for "raw", I always add the r

Comment: I don't think you understand how the r prefix works. You would need it in the definition of `base` if you had not used double backslashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use os.path.join to assist with that

```
def address(name):
    base = "C:\\Users\\example\\"
    address = os.path.join(base,f'{name}.csv')
    return address
```

**Edit:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(address('data01'))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works indeed, next question is, how can I insert address into: ``` df = pd.read_excel(address)```?